# 2D Ising model exact expression for two-point function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

The Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is given by the Hamiltonian $$ H(\sigma)=-\sum_{\{x,y\}}\sigma_x\sigma_y $$ and the Gibbs measure as $$ \frac{\exp(-\beta H(\sigma))}{Z_\beta}\,. $$

There exists an exact solution found by Onsager and re-derived later on by others. My question is:

1. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_lattice_Ising_model) there are explicit expressions for internal energy per site and the spontaneous magnetization (below the critical temperature). Are there any explicit formulas for the infinite-volume two point function $$ \mathbb{E}_\beta[\sigma_x\sigma_y]$$ below, at and above the critical temperature $$  \beta_c = \frac{1}{2}\log(1+\sqrt{2})?$$
2. In case the explicit expressions are too complicated (or too complicated to make conclusions from), I would just like to verify a few things:
   Above the critical temperature we have exponential decay with respect to $\|x-y\|$. Below it we have long range order and hence $$ \mathbb{E}_\beta[\sigma_x\sigma_y] \geq C \qquad(\beta>\beta_c)\,. $$ What is this constant and is it temperature dependent? Clearly it shouldn't be larger than 1. Moreover, *at* the critical temperature, it seems like there should be polynomial behavior $$ \mathbb{E}_{\beta_c}[\sigma_x\sigma_y] \approx \|x-y\|^{-1/{2\pi\beta_c}} \approx \|x-y\|^{-0.361152}\,.  $$
   Is this correct? Is there another expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any explicit formulas for the infinite-volume two point function?

There are indeed explicit expressions. The standard reference is the [book by McCoy and Wu](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674180758); see also [this page](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ising_model:_exact_results).

Concerning your other questions:

> Above the critical temperature we have exponential decay with respect to $\|x−y\|$.

This is correct. The explicit expression for the rate of exponential decay can be found in the links given above.

> What is this constant and is it temperature dependent?

The constant $C$ can be taken to be the square of the spontaneous magnetization; it is indeed temperature dependent (it is a decreasing function of $T$, that tends to $0$ as $T\uparrow T_c$ and to $1$ as $T\downarrow 0$).

Note, however, that the *truncated* two-point function $\langle\sigma_x\sigma_y\rangle - \langle\sigma_x\rangle\langle\sigma_y\rangle$ decays exponentially for all $T\neq T_c$. Again, the rate of exponential decay os given in the above links.

> At the critical temperature, it seems like there should be polynomial behavior

There is indeed algebraic decay, but your exponent is wrong: the correct exponent is $-1/4$.

Comment: Thanks! So the lower bound on the two point function at high temperature is a simple consequence of the Griffiths inequality I suppose.

Comment: Yes, exactly (it hold at all temperatures, but is interesting at *low* temperatures). And it is sharp (it is the correct limit as $\|y-x\|\to \infty$.